# unable to plot polygons in d3.js "format" over leaflet.js

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am doing a very simple implementation of plotting polygons in Leaflet.js using d3.js

I am following this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/

Polygons are plotted correctly, but when zooming in/out most of them are not visualized (even if in DOM I can see these hidden polygons)

You can check http://bl.ocks.org/pere/7370413

Any ideas?

Comment: They all show up for me, at least there don't seem to be any that are in the DOM but not shown. Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @Lars They are all shown at first instance, the problem is when zooming, mostly disappearing. I have tried with all browsers. I really cannot elaborate more than the problem and code itself... :.(

Comment: Ok, I see -- I only zoomed out and that seemed to work fine. It looks like you're positioning of the SVG is off -- maybe the projection of your data doesn't quite agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds were being calculated outside of the reset function so it was using the original zoom (I think this might be a small error in Mikes Bl.ock, although experience has taught me this is rarely the case).  Because the bounds were calculated outside of reset it was using the original zooms bounds and hence you saw the polygons drift.  Also, this stops the polygons being "cut-off" (which occurs in Mike's Bl.ock).

Anyway I bumped your Bl.ock to [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7381401). There are some other minor changes as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! difficult to understand why it works with Mike's code and not with others.. thanks anyway

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, but I don't see what's different between your code and Mike's. I have the same code that you use and I still see the 'cut-off'.

Comment: @Sergi The difference between the two codes is that the variable `bounds` is calculated in the `d3.json` callback in Mike code, so when the `reset` function is called the `bounds` variable is already set.  I moved it inside the `reset` function so it would be recalculated when ever reset was called.  Hope this makes sense.